# Xtion_pro_live Skeleton_tracker cannot work

Tags: ros, skeleton-tracker, asus-xtion-pro-live, openni2, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

```
    I can use xtion pro live by openni2 . `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch`
 I want to use xtion pro live to detect human skeleton . But I cannot use `NiTE v2` as I cannot download it from [here](http://openni.ru/files/nite/index.html). 
 openni2_tracker is cannot use too. 
 And other tutorials like [skeleton_tracker](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker) is also unwork.
 I mean we cannot use skeleton now without NiTE v2 ???
 Or are there any package taht I can use or other way that could solve my problem ? 
 Thanks first!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215175/xtion_pro_live--skeleton_tracker-cannot-work/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @wsAndy !
You can download nite2 from [here](http://openni.ru/files/nite/). If you have issues, follow [these](http://answers.ros.org/question/195459/skeletal-tracker-for-asus-xtion-pro-live/#209413) guidelines. Then you can make this [skeleton_tracker](https://github.com/Chaos84/skeleton_tracker) work.
Please, let me know if you have issues.

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-08-05**:
Chaos , thanks for your answer ! The website you advice me is really good but the problem is that I could not download NiTE2 from this website. I don't know the reason.

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-08-05**:
Then I tried another way . I was surprised to find the NiTE2 is included in this package[cob_people_perception](Then I tried another way . I was surprised to find the NiTE2 is included in this package[here](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=indigo&name=cob_people_perception)

**Comment by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on 2015-08-05**:
Now , I can detect people by skeleton_tracker.

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2016-09-30**:
Chaos, for how long have you ran your skeleton tracker while publishing depth and rgb at the same time? Do you see your program crashing after running for a while? What's the longest you've voluntarily ran your program for?

**Comment by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) on 2016-10-03**:
@Pototo, the last time I used this node was just a couple of weeks ago, and it ran for hours.